# How to understand these mod_rewrite logfile entries?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following in the relevant Apache virtual host configuration:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/path">
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^go\.html$ /out/qs.html?name=value
</Directory>
```

Here is the content of the qs.html file:

```
<html>
 <head><title>Query String</title></head>
 <body>
  <h2>Query String</h2>
  <script>
   document.write("<p>Query String: " + window.location.search.substring(1) + "</p>");
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I send an http request to the server for /path/go.html (without any appended query string), the document is returned but no query string is seen in the rendering of the qs.html document.  I would expect to see the "name=value" query string.

Here is the relevant lines in the logfile with the fluff removed and line numbers added:

```
1. [perdir /var/www/html/path/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/path/go.html -> go.html
2. [perdir /var/www/html/path/] applying pattern '^go\\.html$' to uri 'go.html'
3. [perdir /var/www/html/path/] rewrite 'go.html' -> '/out/qs.html?name=value'
4. split uri=/out/qs.html?name=value -> uri=/out/qs.html, args=name=value
5. [perdir /var/www/html/path/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/html/path/ with /
6. [perdir /var/www/html/path/] internal redirect with /out/qs.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Actually lines 1 thru 3 are pretty much what I would expect and if it just stopped there, I think that I would understand.  What I don't understand is why it's continuing from that point and what the remaining 3 lines are telling me.  Can someone PLEASE help me understand this.  I'm tearing my hair out over this one.  Thanks.

```
     ... doug
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to flag character which can be defined in rewrite rules.

Please refer to https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Also, I can see that their is a mistake in your concept, if you are writing a rewrite rule, you can not read the resulting url through javascript which is client side.

If you really wants to do it, you can use R flag, which will redirect, but in that case purpose of re-writing rule will be defeated.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH!!  So, basically I think what you're saying is that server-side support is required if one wants to obscure the fact that a particular URL has been re-written.  That's an extremely important point.  Additionally, it makes a whole lot of sense.  I guess that it makes so much sense that everyone just assumes that the user is aware of it.  Again, thanks so much for your help.  I'm very glad to finally put this issue behind me.